# Calculate height of divs based on value mentioned below

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm, charts

I have 2 divs which I will be using to demonstrate the money earned every year. The maximum height of the div is **127px** and minimum is **26px**. Now I have to increase and decrease the size of the divs according to the values mentioned below each of them (money). There is no maximum or minimum value for money. Also, if the values are equal, both the divs should be of same size.

> Main points: The height of the div cannot be more than 127px and less than 26px.

I have to achieve this using Javascript.

This is what I had tried. However, this only returns a very small value that is a lot less than 26px. I have tried googling other possibilities but couldn't find any proper solutions. :

```js
let barOne = yearOneValue / 127;
let barOneHeight = barOne / 127;

let barTwo = yearTwoValue / 127;
let barTwoHeight = barTwo / 127;

rootNode.querySelector('.first-graph').style.height = `${barOneHeight}px`;
rootNode.querySelector('.second-graph').style.height = `${barTwoHeight}px`;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to transpose the domain of definition [0, + infinity[ to [a,b] where a = 26 and b = 127. The rest is simple math:

```js
const yearOneValue = 1500000;
const yearTwoValue = 3700;

const maximum = Math.max(yearOneValue,yearTwoValue);

let barOneHeight = yearOneValue / maximum * (127 - 26) + 26;

let barTwoHeight = yearTwoValue / maximum * (127 - 26) + 26;

document.querySelector('.first-graph').style.height = `${barOneHeight}px`;
document.querySelector('.second-graph').style.height = `${barTwoHeight}px`;
```

```css
.first-graph{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}
.second-graph{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-graph"></div>
<div class="second-graph"></div>
```